# Using "the" before a non countable nouns

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, articles, uncountable-nouns

> The decomposition of microscopic animals at the bottom of the sea results in an accumulation of .... in porous rocks.

**the oil / oil**

Which one is correct and why? I know when we are talking about a general abstract, we shouldn't use the before a non countable noun

Comment: It's an arguably over-elliptical sentence to start with. 'The decomposition of microscopic animals at the bottom of the sea results in D oil which then accumulates in porous rocks.' [where D tells us more about the type of oil produced: probably petroleum] doesn't miss out a key step. But if your sentence is standalone, 'the' is out of place. _The_ oil? **What** oil?

Comment: The answer key said it's the oil but i don't know why? Since we are not suppose to use the before non countable nouns

Comment: When I used to teach, it was rare for such poor questions to escape condemnation from moderation boards, and the given answer would have resulted in a walk-out. But then I taught maths.

Comment: Regarding where the decomposition was accumulating: was that a transcription error or were they talking about the pope’s hygiene?

Comment: Is it any old oil or a specific oil?

Comment: Do not trust prepared questions of the "which one is right" variety. As you can see, they're often wrong, don't explain answers, and can't be trusted. Get a different textbook.

Comment: Is this the complete text? As Hot Licks says, it depends on whether you're talking about specific oil or mentioning oil being formed.

Comment: It's just that. It's originally a multiple question but I couldn't figure out between these two and the answer is suppose to be "the oil"

Comment: If there's a specific oil mentioned earlier in the context, then "the oil" is the correct answer. If there's no previous context, then "oil" is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

As gotube points out, it is impossible to say which is correct without seeing the complete context, which you mentioned does exist.

For example, the passage could read:

> There is sometimes oil present on the sea floor. The decomposition of microscopic animals at the bottom of the sea results in an accumulation of .... in porous rocks.

Here "the oil" would be correct, as it refers back to *the specific oil* that is the subject of the passage as a whole. This is an awkward way of writing it; given that the oil itself is the subject, I would expect it to come at the beginning of the sentence:

> The oil accumulates in porous rocks due to the decomposition of microscopic animals at the bottom of the sea.

---

But if instead the full context was:

> Many factors affect the makeup of materials on the sea floor. The decomposition of microscopic animals at the bottom of the sea results in an accumulation of .... in porous rocks. Ocean currents move scouring sand across the sea bed. From time to time, a dead whale will drop to the bottom and provide a both food and habitat for scavengers.

...then the oil mentioned is just one of several things, and is not the subject of the passage as a whole. In this case "oil" without the definite article would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The decomposition of microscopic animals at the bottom of the sea results in "the" accumulation of oil in porous rocks.

Shouldn't it be "the" since this accumulation is assumed to be a result of the decomposition?

Comment: Hey Deejay, and welcome to the forum! Your answer here feels more like a comment than an answer, so use the "Add a comment" link. An "answer" should be something the original poster (OP) could select as one that satisfies their question.